# How to confirm that the patient has neither cold or flu

Tags: prolog

I'm looking at this `cold_flu.pl` sample prolog application.

```
%Flu or cold identification example
%Start with ?- go.

go:- hypothesis(Disease),
    write('I believe you have: '),
    write(Disease),
    nl,
    undo.

%Hypothesis that should be tested
hypothesis(cold):- cold, !.
hypothesis(flu):- flu, !.

%Hypothesis Identification Rules
cold :-
       verify(headache),
       verify(runny_nose),
       verify(sneezing),
       verify(sore_throat).
flu :-
       verify(fever),
       verify(headache),
       verify(chills),
       verify(body_ache).

/* how to ask questions */
ask(Question) :-
    write('Does the patient have the following symptom: '),
    write(Question),
    write('? '),
    read(Response),
    nl,
    ( (Response == yes ; Response == y)
      ->
       assert(yes(Question)) ;
       assert(no(Question)), fail).

:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.

/* How to verify something */
verify(S) :- (yes(S) -> true ;
               (no(S)  -> write('failed') ;
               ask(S))).

/* undo all yes/no assertions */
undo :- retract(yes(_)),fail.
undo :- retract(no(_)),fail.
undo.
```

I notice that if asked:

```
Does the patient have the following symptom: headache?
```

and the response is `no.` then the program will fail because the only two possible outcomes declare that the patient has a headache.

How would you edit it so that it would end cleanly with a message saying that its unlikely to be either the cold of flu?

I don't know any Prolog but have tried a few things liike adding a hypothesis rule for `nothing`.

Comment: `I don't know any Prolog` you should start with [syntactic unification]. Learning Prolog on your own with out a book or mentor is hard. If you know another programming language then it is even harder because you will keep trying to leverage your other programming knowledge with Prolog and more than not fail.

Comment: Yes, I can see that already. I just want to get a lititle familiarity with it. I'll take a look at `syntactic unification`.